# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-117, SQLSTATE=42802, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.68.61

Tags: java, sql, db2, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I'm experiencing this problem while developing in Java and inserting records into a DB2 database.

```
sqlInsert = "INSERT into SI_Orders (SellersNo,OrderDate,ShipDatePlanned,"
            + "Warehouse,OrderType,ShipToName,ShipToAddress1,"
            + "ShipToCity,ShipToProvState,ShipToPostalZip,ShipToCountry" + ") "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?,'01','DO','bob','a','toronto','ON','h0h0h0','CA')";

    try {
        con = dc.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        db2Stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

        for (Order order : orderWrapper.orders) {
            save1 = con.setSavepoint();
            db2Stmt.setString(1, order.getOrderId());
            db2Stmt.setTimestamp(2, shipStnDateFormat( order.getOrderDate() ) );            
            db2Stmt.setString(3, null); // PONo
             /*
             * db2Stmt.setTimestamp(4, shipStnDateFormat(order.getShipByDate()));
             */
            db2Stmt.executeUpdate();    
            //con.commit();
        } // end of enhanced for each block
    } // end of try block

    catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back.");
                con.rollback();
            } 

            catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } // end of if(con != null) block
    } // end of catch block
    finally {
        // Clean-up code
        con.setAutoCommit(true);

        if (db2Stmt != null) {
            db2Stmt.close();
        }

        if (con !=null){
            con.close();
        }
    } // end of finally block
} // end of insertDB method

private Timestamp shipStnDateFormat(String shipByDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat shipStnDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat standardDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String parsedFinalFormattedDate = null;
    Date finalDate = null;

    if (shipByDate == null)
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(0); // return a dummy value

    else {
        try {
            Date parsedShipByDate = shipStnDateFormat.parse(shipByDate); //
            parsedFinalFormattedDate = standardDateFormat.format(parsedShipByDate); //
            finalDate = standardDateFormat.parse(parsedFinalFormattedDate); //
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new java.sql.Timestamp(finalDate.getTime());
    } // end of else statement
} // end of shipStnDateFormat method`
```

I get this error...
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-117, SQLSTATE=42802, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.6in8.61

Obviously, I'd like it to insert all three columns without throwing a SQL Exception.

Also, here's the DDL I used to create the table which shows the datatypes of each column and whether a NOT NULL constraint is enforced or not.

The first column "OrderId" is an identity column, so I haven't issued an insert parameter for that.

```
CREATE TABLE SI_Orders (
OrderId INTEGER NOT NULL generated always as identity (start with 0, 
increment by 1, no cache),
SellersNo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
OrderDate Timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
PONo VARCHAR(20),
ShipDatePlanned Timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_SI_Orders PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
);
```

Comment: Did you look up what "SQLCODE=-117, SQLSTATE=42802" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting:

```
db2Stmt.setString(3, null); // PONo
```

While your model states for that column:

```
ShipDatePlanned Timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
```

So setting it to NULL is not allowed, update parameter 3 to a not NULL value should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I entered a string value of "NULL" instead of null. I still get an SQLException...DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-180, SQLSTATE=22007, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.68.61. Which means "The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect." It seems that it's expecting an input for the ShipDatePlanned column. If so, why did it skip setting the third column (PONo) to "NULL"?

Comment: Oh, missed that part in my answer: The column needs to be a timestamp not a string.

Comment: ok cool...so I set that string to a timestamp and it works. I have another problem...In my create table DDL (shown in my question), it lists OrderId (an identity column), SellersNo, OrderDate, and PONo. Starting from SellersNo with an index number of 1, I would expect PONo to have an index number of 3. So when I do this... `db2Stmt.setString(3, "2017-06-01");`                                                                    I would expect it would try to place this timestamp in the PoNo column, why does it place it in the ShipDatePlanned column, which I'd expect to have an index number of 4?

Comment: The number of `?` determine the count index in `db2Stmt.set`. It is not related to the xth column of your table or query.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it...so how would I set a value for PONo?

Answer (score 1):

To add columns to a query you would do this:

```
sqlInsert = "INSERT into SI_Orders (SellersNo,OrderDate,ShipDatePlanned,PONo,"
        + "Warehouse,OrderType,ShipToName,ShipToAddress1,"
        + "ShipToCity,ShipToProvState,ShipToPostalZip,ShipToCountry" + ") "
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,'01','DO','bob','a','toronto','ON','h0h0h0',?)";
```

So adding a column at a random location in the string, and adding a ? in the VALUES would add the column.

The index of the ? starts with 1 and matches only up the the column name which the parameter is replaced with.

For example: In this sample `ShipToCountry` would be index `5`

Comment: I have added some columns to this query and now I'm getting the following error...                                                
`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.68.61`